# (React Native) - Fonts not loading on first app load

Tags: javascript, react-native, fonts, mobile-application

I'm using custom fonts in my App.

The code I use to load fonts is the following:

```
let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
 Montserrat_100Thin,
 Montserrat_200ExtraLight,
 Montserrat_300Light,
 Montserrat_400Regular,
 Montserrat_500Medium,
 Montserrat_600SemiBold,
 Montserrat_700Bold,
 Montserrat_800ExtraBold,
 Montserrat_900Black,
 Montserrat_100Thin_Italic,
 Montserrat_200ExtraLight_Italic,
 Montserrat_300Light_Italic,
 Montserrat_400Regular_Italic,
 Montserrat_500Medium_Italic,
 Montserrat_600SemiBold_Italic,
 Montserrat_700Bold_Italic,
 Montserrat_800ExtraBold_Italic,
 Montserrat_900Black_Italic,
});
```

As soon as the app is loaded, it uses the system default font, but if I navigate to a new screen, the new fonts appear.

If I edit the screen which uses default fonts through hot reload, the new fonts appear as well.

The warning I get when the custom fonts are not displayed is "fontFamily 'Montserrat_600SemiBold' is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync".